# Некорректно работает цикл while с вложенным в него циклом for и условием if, Java

Tags: java, массивы, if, while, for

Решаю [задачку](https://www.codewars.com/kata/57b06f90e298a7b53d000a86/train/java) на очередь из произвольного числа покупателей у `*n*` касс в супермаркете, где очередь задается массивом целых чисел, каждое из которых означает время обслуживания соответствующего покупателя в кассе.

Возникла проблема в самом сложном случае, когда число касс больше одной (`n > 1`) и при этом число покупателей в очереди больше, чем число касс (`customers.length > n`).

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Solution {

    public static int solveSuperMarketQueue(int[] customers, int n) {
        int sum = 0;
        int[] nCustomers;
        int[] restOfCustomers;
        if (customers.length == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if (customers.length == 1) {
            return customers[0];
        } else {
            if (n == 0) {
                return 0;
            } else if (n == 1) {
                sum = sumOfArray(customers);
            } else if (customers.length <= n) {
                int customerMax = customers[0];
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    if (customers[i] > customerMax) {
                        customerMax = customers[i];
                    }
                }
                return customerMax;
            } else {
                nCustomers = Arrays.copyOfRange(customers, 0, n);
                restOfCustomers = Arrays.copyOfRange(customers, n, customers.length);
                int serviceTime = 0;

                while (sumOfArray(nCustomers) > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < nCustomers.length; i++) {
                        nCustomers[i]--;

                        if (nCustomers[i] == 0) {
                            nCustomers[i] = restOfCustomers[0];
                            restOfCustomers = Arrays.copyOfRange(restOfCustomers, 1, restOfCustomers.length);
                        }
                        serviceTime++;
                    }
                    return serviceTime;

                }

            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static int sumOfArray(int ary[]) {
        int s = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
            s += ary[i];
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

А именно этот фрагмент:

```
} else {
  nCustomers = Arrays.copyOfRange(customers, 0, n);
  restOfCustomers = Arrays.copyOfRange(customers, n, customers.length);
  int serviceTime = 0;

  while (sumOfArray(nCustomers) > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nCustomers.length; i++) {
      nCustomers[i]--;

    if (nCustomers[i] == 0) {
      nCustomers[i] = restOfCustomers[0];
      restOfCustomers = Arrays.copyOfRange(restOfCustomers, 1, restOfCustomers.length);
    }
    serviceTime++;
  }
  return serviceTime;

  }
```

Здесь я разбил массив покупателей из условия `customers` на два подмассива - `nCustomers` (это те первые `n` покупателей, что подошли к `n` кассам) и `restOfCustomers` (это оставшаяся очередь).

Мои рассуждения такие: пока у касс кто-то есть, мы запускаем счетчик времени на обслуживание `serviceTime`, уменьшая за каждую итерацию каждый элемент массива `nCustomers` на единицу.

После каждой итерации проверяем, не обнулился ли какой-нибудь элемент в этом массиве, и если обнулился, то ему присваиваем первый элемент из подмассива оставшейся очереди `restOfCustomers`, а сам этот подмассив укорачиваем на этот передаваемый в `nCustomers` элемент.

Подскажите - ошибся ли я в логике решения или логика правильная, а реализация в коде неправильная?

Comment: приведите отступы в порядок, ошибка будет заметнее. И когда очередь кончается, ваша программа вылетает.

Answer (score 2):

- `sumOfArray(nCustomers)` и `nCustomers[i]--;` - после декремента времени обслуживания клиента может может получиться отрицательное значение, когда в каких-либо кассах обслуживание уже завершено и нет новых клиентов.
- `if (nCustomers[i] == 0)` - в этот if мы, опять таки, попадем, когда обслуживание не завершено в какой-либо из касс, а очередь уже пуста, т.е. `restOfCustomers.length == 0`. Соответственно - выход за границу массива.

Поправил неточности в коде, вроде, считает.
Поправленный вариант `solveSuperMarketQueue`:

```
public static int solveSuperMarketQueue(int[] customers, int n) {
    
    int sum = 0;
    int[] nCustomers;
    int[] restOfCustomers;
    if (customers.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (customers.length == 1) {
        return customers[0];
    } else {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if (n == 1) {
            sum = sumOfArray(customers);
            return sum;
        } else if (customers.length <= n) {
            int customerMax = customers[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (customers[i] > customerMax) {
                    customerMax = customers[i];
                }
            }
            return customerMax;
        } else {
            
            nCustomers = Arrays.copyOfRange(customers, 0, n); // раскидал по n кассам n покупателей 
            restOfCustomers = Arrays.copyOfRange(customers, n, customers.length); // сохранил оставшуюся очередь
            int serviceTime = 0; // время обслуживания
            
            while (sumOfArray(nCustomers) > 0) {  // цикл пока кассы обслуживают очередь
                serviceTime++; // учли минуту обслуживания
                for (int i = 0; i < nCustomers.length; i++) { // цикл перебора касс
                    if (nCustomers[i] > 0) {
                        nCustomers[i]--;
                    }  // минута работы кассы
                    if (nCustomers[i] == 0 && restOfCustomers.length > 0) { // если касса обслужила клиента
                        nCustomers[i] = restOfCustomers[0]; // взяли на обслуживание следующего
                        restOfCustomers = Arrays.copyOfRange(restOfCustomers, 1, restOfCustomers.length); // убрали из очереди обслуживаемого клиента
                    }
                }
            }
            return serviceTime;  
        }
    }
}
```